# why jsf page(buttons) works only after refresh

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean

I'm working on a JSF project, all is working fine for the moment except for one thing: when I select a page from the left side bar, it is loaded correctly, when I click on a button, the button stays pressed but the action is not called. 
[button pressed but no action called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AVzS.png)
When I refresh the page and press it again, it works fine.
This happens to the other pages too.
Do you have any idea why is this happening ?!

I'm here to provide more details if needed!

The managed bean name and scope:

```
@ManagedBean(name="ModerateurBean")
@SessionScoped
```

The code of one of my pages:

```
 <ui:composition template="template/default/main.xhtml"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
        >


<ui:define name="content">
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">  


 <h:form id="form">
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />


<p:commandButton process="singleDT" update=":form:ajouter" icon="ui-icon-plus" value="Ajouter" oncomplete="PF('ajouterDialog').show()" />
<p:dataTable id="singleDT" var="o" value="#{ModerateurBean.listMod}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur}" rowKey="#{o.id_personne}" valueChangeListener="#{ModerateurBean.valChanged}" onchange="submit()">


        <p:column headerText="Nom ">
            <h:outputText value="#{o.nom}" />
        </p:column>
         <p:column headerText="Prénom ">
            <h:outputText value="#{o.prenom}" />
        </p:column>
         <p:column headerText="Cin ">
            <h:outputText value="#{o.cin}" />
        </p:column>
         <p:column headerText="Adresse ">
            <h:outputText value="#{o.adresse}" />
        </p:column>

       <p:column headerText="Numéro Téléphone ">
            <h:outputText value="#{o.numtel}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
     <p:commandButton process="singleDT" update=":form:voir" icon="ui-icon-search" value="Voir" oncomplete="PF('voirDialog').show()" />
     <p:commandButton process="singleDT" update=":form:modifier" icon="ui-icon-pencil" value="Modifier" oncomplete="PF('modifierDialog').show()" />
     <p:commandButton process="singleDT" update=":form:supprimer" icon="ui-icon-trash" value="Supprimer" oncomplete="PF('supprimerDialog').show()" />





  <!-- dialog voir admin -->
        <p:dialog header="Details administrateur" widgetVar="voirDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="voir" style="text-align:center;">
            <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur}" columnClasses="label,value">



                <h:outputText value="Nom" style="color:black"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.nom}" />

                <h:outputText value="Prénom " style="color:black" />
                <h:outputText value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.prenom}" />

                 <h:outputText value="Cin " style="color:black" />
                <h:outputText value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.cin}" />

                 <h:outputText value="Adresse " style="color:black" />
                <h:outputText value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.adresse}" />

                <h:outputText value="Numéro Téléphone "  style="color:black"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.numtel}" />


            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>

      <!-- dialog modifier moderateur -->
        <p:dialog header="Modifier moderateur" widgetVar="modifierDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="modifier" style="text-align:center;">

            <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur}" columnClasses="label,value">


                <h:outputText value="Nom" style="color:black" />
                <p:inputText value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.nom}" />

                 <h:outputText value="Prénom " style="color:black" />
               <p:inputText value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.prenom}" />


                <h:outputText value="Cin " style="color:black"/>
                <p:inputText value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.cin}" />

                 <h:outputText value="Adresse " style="color:black" />
             <p:inputTextarea rows="6" cols="33"  value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.adresse}"/>

           <h:outputText value="Numéro Téléphone " style="color:black" />
               <p:inputMask id="phoneWithExt18"  value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.numtel}" mask="(999) 999-9999? x99999"/>      



            </p:panelGrid>
           </p:outputPanel>
        <p:commandButton action="#{ModerateurBean.ModifierModerateur}" icon="ui-icon-pencil"  value="Modifier" update="@form"  />
     <p:commandButton process="singleDT" update="@form" icon="ui-icon-cancel" value="Annuler" oncomplete="PF('modifierDialog').hide()" />
    </p:dialog>

     <!-- dialog ajouter moderateur -->
        <p:dialog header="Ajouter moderateur" widgetVar="ajouterDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="ajouter" style="text-align:center;">

            <p:panelGrid  columns="2"  columnClasses="label,value">


                <h:outputText value="Nom" style="color:black" />
                <p:inputText value="#{ModerateurBean.nom}" />

                <h:outputText value="Prénom " style="color:black" />
                <p:inputText value="#{ModerateurBean.prenom}" />

                 <h:outputText value="Sexe " for="sexe" style="color:black" />
                 <p:selectOneMenu id="sexe" value="#{ModerateurBean.sexe}">

                 <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="  --selectionnez--  "></f:selectItem>
                 <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Homme"></f:selectItem>
                 <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Femme"></f:selectItem>

                 </p:selectOneMenu>
                  <h:outputText value="Cin " style="color:black" />
                <p:inputText value="#{ModerateurBean.cin}" />

                 <h:outputText value="Adresse " style="color:black"/>

                <p:inputTextarea rows="6" cols="33"  vvalue="#{ModerateurBean.adresse}"/>


                  <h:outputText value="Numéro Téléphone " style="color:black" />

                <p:inputMask id="phoneWithExt1" value="#{ModerateurBean.numtel}"  mask="(999) 999-9999? x99999"/>



            </p:panelGrid>
           </p:outputPanel>
        <p:commandButton  update="@form" icon="ui-icon-check" value="Sauvegarder"  action="#{ModerateurBean.AjouterModerateur}"  oncomplete="PF('ajouterDialog').hide()"  >
        <f:ajax render="singleDT" update="@form"/></p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton process="singleDT" update="@form" icon="ui-icon-cancel" value="Annuler" oncomplete="PF('ajouterDialog').hide()" />
    </p:dialog>

  <!-- dialog supprimer moderateur -->
        <p:dialog header="Supprimer moderateur" widgetVar="supprimerDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="supprimer" style="text-align:center;">
            <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur}" columnClasses="label,value">
           <h:outputText value="Id " style="color:black"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.id_personne}" />

                <h:outputText value="Nom" style="color:black"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.nom}" />

                <h:outputText value="Prénom " style="color:black"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{ModerateurBean.selectedModerateur.prenom}" />



            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
        <p:commandButton value="Supprimer" action="#{ModerateurBean.SupprimerModerateur}" icon="ui-icon-trash" oncomplete="PF('supprimerDialog').hide()" update="@form" >
         <p:commandButton process="singleDT" update="@form" icon="ui-icon-cancel" value="Annuler" oncomplete="PF('supprimerDialog').hide()" />

        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Etes vous sur?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
        </p:commandButton>

    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
        <p:commandButton value="Oui" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="Non" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
    </p:dialog>



</h:form>


 </div>
  </div>
   </div>   



    </ui:define>





        </ui:composition>
```

The images : [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V9TD.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzEW6.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyE5F.png)

[image 4 : When i click on a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPtZi.png)

Comment: Why would anyone here know what is wrong with your code with out you posting it?

Comment: The code is working fine, its just that problem of refreshing the page !

Comment: The browser executes your code to create a webpage, if your code is only working when you refresh the page, then chances are you code is not working fine.    There could be a million issues that are occuring, and your basically asking everyone to take guess.  Instead of posting the relevant code.

Comment: I'll update the question and add the code.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just trying to help you get an answer. When I start using stack I posted the same way.  I just wanted general information, but for that you can post in the Chat's when you gain priviledges

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate it. I posted the page code,if you need more information i'll provide it.

Comment: @johnny5: Better to always ask for a [mcve] (by typing [ mcve ] without the spaces. The code above is a 'snippet' and there can be many cause outside this code that can cause this behaviour. In fact there are multiple  JSF  Q/A about 'first click not working' or 'only second click working' or similar...

Comment: @johnny5 here is some things i found while checking the console on Chrome ..see the images in the update!

Comment: @Kukeltje please see the images in the update!

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks in didn’t know you could do it that way I always thought people were posting that manually

Comment: @MáÝdá: Couple of things. Please narrow down the problem. Always do. Hoe is it Hibernate related (a tag means the problem is, most likely,  in that part/component/framework. 99.9% of the JSF questions are not both 
Hibernate AND JSF related and Java-ee is to broad. Try with a plain static array or something. And your code is not a [mcve]. There is on one side to much detail in it (all the col stuff, template related things, dialogs and more) and also to little (there could be things in the template causing this). So always minimize. Helps narrowing down the problem and us helping you better!

Comment: And all these network traffic errors should be investigated first. Might it be that everything loads so slow that when you click things, not everything is loaded?

Comment: @johnny5 [ask] works by adding [ ask ]...

Comment: @Kukeltje thnaks for the clarifications , i will apply it in future questions .

Comment: I think you should apply it here to if you still are seeking a solution

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Kukeltje :) i found the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Resume of the problem :
My problem was that when i click on a button it stays pressed but when i refresh the page it starts working normaly.

The solution :
i am working with facelets, so i have a template as you can see it here [template structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jrNM.png)

In main.xhtml i gather them and define styesheets and scripts in the head section, i work also with primefaces 6.x.

After i investagated in the console of Chrome [Console of Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JvvR.png) , the googlable errors stated that the probleme was in the conflict between primefaces and jquery that i manualy added.

what i did is remove all the jquery scripts and it started working again.
see the diffrence in the two codes :

main.xhtml (before)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">

    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

            <title>App Gestion d'Absence</title>
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="middle">

         <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
         <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
          <h:outputStylesheet name="css/dashboard.css" />
          <h:outputStylesheet name="metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" />
          <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/sb-admin-2.css" />
          <h:outputStylesheet name="morrisjs/morris.css" />
          <h:outputStylesheet name="morrisjs/morris.min.js" />
          <h:outputStylesheet name="morrisjs/morris.js" />
          <h:outputStylesheet name="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
          <h:outputStylesheet name="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
          <h:outputStylesheet name="vendor/morrisjs/morris.css"/>
<!--       <h:outputStylesheet name="webjars/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css"> -->



          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>

             <!-- jQuery -->



   <h:outputScript library="bootstrap" name="bootstrap.js" />
   <h:outputScript library="bootstrap" name="bootstrap.min.js" />   


   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>          



        <h:outputScript library="js" name="sb-admin-2.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="sb-admin-2.min.js" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="last">

        </f:facet>

    </h:head>



<h:body>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <div id="header">
    <ui:insert name="header">
        <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/> 
    </ui:insert>
       </div>

 <div id="leftMenu">
    <ui:insert name="leftMenu">
        <ui:include src="leftMenu.xhtml"/> 
    </ui:insert>
       </div>




<div id="content">
  <ui:insert name="content">


      <!-- <div> 
        <ui:include src="content.xhtml"/> 
         </div>  --> 
  </ui:insert>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <ui:insert name="footer">

    <ui:include src="footer.xhtml"/>  
  </ui:insert>
</div> 
    </h:body>
</html>
```

main.xhtml (after)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">

    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

            <title>Gestion Absence ISMO</title>
        </f:facet>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#{resources['images/favicon.ico']}" type="image/x-icon" /> 

        <f:facet name="middle">

         <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
          <h:outputStylesheet name="css/dashboard.css" />
          <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/sb-admin-2.css" />
           <h:outputStylesheet name="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
            <h:outputStylesheet name="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<!--          <h:outputStylesheet name="webjars/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css"> -->

       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" />

        <h:outputScript name="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" />
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="last">

        </f:facet>

    </h:head>



<h:body>
       <div id="header">
    <ui:insert name="header">
        <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/> 
    </ui:insert>
       </div>

 <div id="leftMenu">
    <ui:insert name="leftMenu">
        <ui:include src="leftMenu.xhtml"/> 
    </ui:insert>
       </div>




<div id="content">
  <ui:insert name="content">


      <!-- <div> 
        <ui:include src="content.xhtml"/> 
         </div>  --> 
  </ui:insert>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <ui:insert name="footer">

    <ui:include src="footer.xhtml"/>  
  </ui:insert>
</div> 
    </h:body>
</html>
```

i hope this will help someone :)

Comment: Waaaay to much totally irrelevant code in ypur answer. And see, cause was totally somewhere else and you firsthand experiemced the great advantage of an [mcve]

Comment: @Kukeltje as you said, next time i ll make sure to see all the sides of the issue.